# Chart.js - Line Chart format data to Lacs/Crores

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wt99cvpb/)

I am using `ChartJs` http://www.chartjs.org/ in my project.

While using `Line Chart`, I populate data with numbers. The requirement is to convert the numbers to lacs/crores.

When I convert the numbers to `lacs/crores` & apply these values to the Chart, the Chart doesn't display any lines, but i can see the actual data converted in lacs/crores as a tooltip.

```
var lineChartData = {
    "datasets": [{
        "data": [
        numConvertion(10000000),
        numConvertion(12000000),
        numConvertion(18000000),
        numConvertion(22000000)],
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    }],
        "labels": [
        "Jun-2015",
        "July-2015",
        "Aug-2015",
        "Sep-2015", ]
};
```

How to solve this issue for displaying numbers in lacs/crores format in chart.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the chart's `scaleLabel` option to format your Y axis label. I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt99cvpb/1/)

Comment: Works Perfectly...Is it also possible to change the format in the tooltip?

Comment: yes. Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt99cvpb/2/). And one more thing please accept the answer if it helped.:)